# How to create a NodeJS + LoopBack Application using WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, loopbackjs

I am using WebStorm v 9.0.3. I would like to create a Strongloop/Loopback Application + NodeJS Application. Is there a way to create it directly through WebStorm IDE or should we manually do it using commandline.

Currently I can see only NodeJS Express App provision during project creation in WebStorm.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS System.

Kindly help me do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `slc loopback` and follow the menus with what you need. Then just drag the folder to webstorm.

For creating the models it is easy with the terminal too. Every model or stuff you create it will be reflected in WebStorm then you can easily edit there.

For running also it is easy with the command `slc run`.

There is no way with WebStorm IDE. At least yet...

Answer (score 7):

Creating makes not too much sense as all generators are command line tools. You can of course run the generators from your webstorm console. For debugging you can create a node run configuration:

[image: Run Config]

Comment: Very useful screenshot. For me the path was: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/bin/slc`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to scaffold the app in Webstorm directly ATM (if you want to see this feature, please read https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/wiki/Issues and submit a feature request)

That said, you can scaffold the project using the command line via `slc loopback` then simply open the project in WebStorm.